# Jquery/PHP + Create MySQL Date Type

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date

I have a site that people join and enter their birthdate which I want to store in MySQL as a date Type.

The data I have is

```
Day - eg: 1 or 11, 23 etc
Month - eg: March or April or December
Year - eg: 1975 or 1964 or 1944 etc

thus eg: 3 March 1966
```

How can I convert this into a format that can be saved into as a MySQL date type?

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('j F Y', '3 March 1966');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CJuTb7)

Reference:

- [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0):

it can be created using date() and strtotime() functions

```
 $mysql_date= date("Y-m-d",strtotime("3 March 1996"));
```

[working demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/k0myqm)